# How to iterate an array of JSON objects in angular/TS?

Tags: angular

I have an array of JSON objects fetched through an API call, stored in a variable named `dataInfo : any`,

```
[
  {
    "City": "SGM",
    "State": "Rajasthan",
    "District": "Ganganagar"
  },
  {
    "City": "A.Thirumuruganpoondi",
    "State": "Tamil Nadu",
    "District": "Coimbatore"
  }
.
.
.
]
```

I want to loop through this 'dataInfo' array and get all the states and store in another array but I get an error `ERROR TypeError: this.dataInfo is not iterable` when I use  `for (let x of this.datInfo)`  to loop.
I have also tried to use `.map` and `Object.keys` but it gives error.

(I want to use this method outside `.subscribe()`)

How can I achieve this inside my .ts file ?

Below is my code -

export class GeoComponent implements OnInit {

dataInfo: any ;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() {

```
let response = this.http.get("https://indian-cities-api- 
nocbegfhqg.now.sh/cities");
response.subscribe((data) => this.dataInfo = data
);

this.sortData();
```

}

sortData() {

```
// TYPE CODE HERE
```

}

}

Comment: make sure there is data in variable and try to use it after data comes from API inside subscribe block

Comment: Yes, dataInfo has data populated in it and I am trying to write a function outside the subscribe block for which I need to iterate the dataInfo array.

Comment: call that function from inside subscribe

Comment: Great ! Thanks!! It worked !!!

I would also like to ask , how can I remove duplicate values from this array ? I am new to Angular, sure will have to write some logic but was wondering if there is a simpler way/or command to achieve this?

Comment: The JavaScript exception `"is not iterable"` occurs when the value which is given as the right hand-side of `for…of` or as argument of a function such as `Promise.all` or `TypedArray.from`, is not an iterable object. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/is_not_iterable]

Comment: @akhouri Thanks for sharing the link ! Yes, json objects are non iterable for which we need to desrialize them or convert to string which can be achieved by the method posted below by @ thisdotutkarsh .
Both the methods are working fine ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have imported & declared HttpClient & HttpClientModule correctly. You can do the following,

```
this.httpClient.get(this.baseURL + "/api-endpoint").subscribe((res: any) => {
     this.datInfo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    },
    () => {
      this.sortData()
     }
   )
  }

sortData() {
 // Code to Sort this.datInfo
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your solution ! But, it still throws the not-iterable error. 
I called the sortData() from within the subscribe block and it fixed the issue.

Comment: @ItykaBandta Glad to know that you were able to resolve the issue. However, I would like to point out that in the answer I gave, the `sortData()` function is being called within the `onCompleted` callback in `subscription`.

Comment: Oh yes ! My bad. Thanks ! :D